# Change Magento Product List, Product Link Text

Tags: magento, e-commerce, php

```
Example URL: http://www.yourjigsawpuzzles.co.uk/category/wasgij.html
```

That is a list of all Wasgij products.

Each listing has it's own product URL and Link Text

```
Example: Wasgij Original 18 - Uproar At The Vets Jigsaw Puzzle
```

Is there a way to change the URL link text, like above, to a custom product attribute that I've created?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can check your template: /app/design/frontend/default/gl2/template/catalog/product/list.phtml. and see which attribute is being called... I can guess in your magento backend of the product / category you can simply edit an attribute on product. looks like category name - product name. But have a look.

Comment: I can see the attribute that is being called (I think) but when I change it, it just removes the whole text line... I must be doing something wrong. The only problem with editing the product name on the backend is that I want the product name and the category link text to be different.